# How to configure Jetbrain phpstorm add action buttons to main menu / tool bar such as redo and undo buttons instead of CTRL+Y and CTRL+SHIFT+Z?

Tags: button, menu, toolbar, program-entry-point, phpstorm-2018.1

I installed new version of Phpstorm 2018. And by default it does not have undo/redo button in the main menu. I am not sure how to add them back.

New Phpstorm version 2018 Problem of hiding Back and Forward buttons, how do i show them on main menu / tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any action buttons you wish to the toolbar by right clicking on empty space in toolbar or via "Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars"

[image]

from source:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000164644-New-Update-Problem-with-Back-and-Forward-buttons